# Call subprogram in Shell Script using While Loop

Tags: shell, loops, input

I'm trying to read a file that contains arguments for my subprogram named `batcher.sh`. I'm using a `while` loop to read the arguments line by line and pass them to the subprogram.

The issue I'm facing is, only the first loop iteration gets executed. The SubProgram basically calls a stored procedure as shown:

```
#!/bin/sh
input=/user/location/filename.out
while read line
do
        Name=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
        Class=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
        age=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f3)
        echo $Name $Class $age 
        cd /users/run/program/sample/bin/   
        ./batcher.sh RUN_CLASS_STRNTH -N $Name -C $Class -a $age >  /user/location/logs/class_strength`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log
done < "$input"
exit $?
```

Records in The filename.out

```
BAL C1 23
JANE C3 32
```

Subprogram gets triggered successfully for **BAL** and then it exists.

Comment: Your example as such should not exhibit the behavior you describe. What are the symptoms? What's the exit code? Do you get an error message?

Comment: As an aside, `while read -r Name Class age` would be more idiomatic and economical.

Comment: However, each iteration overwrires the output file, so if processing takes less than one minute, you would expect to find the *last* (not first) output left in the file.

Comment: Agreed triplee Since my process iteration process is completing within a minute my log file always has the  latest argument snapshot. From the Issue perspective i update the While Loop based on your/Jens comment and now im able to iterate thru the loop. Thanks ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect the loop's output, otherwise each iteration of the loop will overwrite the output from the previous iteration.

I have also refactored some other parts.

```
#!/bin/sh
input=/user/location/filename.out
cd /users/run/program/sample/bin/
while read -r Name Class age; do
    echo "$Name $Class $age"
    ./batcher.sh RUN_CLASS_STRNTH -N "$Name" -C "$Class" -a "$age" 
done < "$input" >  /user/location/logs/class_strength`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log
```

The `exit $?` is completely redundant so I took it out. Perhaps your script should return nonzero if any iteration failed?

Answer (score 2):

Reading a line and picking it apart with echo and cut is extremely cumbersome. The `read` built-in accepts more than one variable name:

```
 while read Name Class age rest; do
     echo $Name $Class $age
 done
```

That should get you started.

The second problem might be that the `./batcher` program also reads from stdin, reading the rest of your input. To avoid that, redirect stdin from `/dev/null`:

```
 ./batcher.sh  ... </dev/null
```

You can verify that this is actually the problem by commenting out the batcher run. If the loop then runs for all lines, that was the problem.

Nitpick: Note that repeatedly doing `cd directory` is also useless. Once is enough.

Comment: nitpick: if some script _need_ something from the `stdin`, usually will not be happy with the content of the `/dev/null`... ;) ;) +1